# My C Program Keep Crashing

Tags: c, runtime-error, runtimeexception

i am trying to create an program to generate empty files. but when it try to run the program it crashes after taking inputs from the console .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int create(char* filename)
{
    char filext[10];
    printf("\nEnter File Extension :");
    fgets(filext);
        FILE* fp;
        fp = fopen(strcat(filename,strcat(".",filext)),"w");
        if(!fp)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;

}
int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    int f;
    int i;
    char buffer[33];
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[2]) ; i++)
        {
            f = create(strcat(argv[1],itoa(i,buffer,10)));
            if(f==0)
            {
                printf("error in creating files . check uac!!!");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nfile Created ...\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("syntax Error");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to run this program I get the following output

```
F:\selfcreatedtools\filegen>gcc gen.c

F:\selfcreatedtools\filegen>a level 100

Enter File Extension :php
```

after entering the extension the program crashes.
i am a beginner in c programming.

Comment: You can't do `strcat(argv[1], …)` because there isn't any space in `argv[1]` for extra material.  You have to allocate the space somehow.  Similarly for other lines where you use `strcat()`.  And [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used, ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: `argv[1]` and `"."` have no extra space to combine strings.

Comment: Use of `gets()` is dangerous. Try `fgets()`.

Comment: can you give me an example.

Comment: @J...S thank you for the information. I have changed it.

Comment: E.g `char path[FILENAME_MAX + 1]; snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s%d", argv[1], i);`...

Comment: Also, `strcat(".",filext)` attempts to modify a string literal; they're often stored in readonly memory and a crash is a very common consequence.  Look up [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html).  Also, prompting for the extension is probably not the best interface; that should be a command line argument too.

Comment: `char filext[10+1]="."; scanf("%9s", filext+1); /* check length of result then*/ strcat(filename, filext);`

Comment: Please explain *program crashes*. What do you mean? Do you get an error message? Exit with no message? Freezes? What?

Comment: @lurker it just stops responding. and terminates

Comment: thank you @JonathanLeffler for letting me know. I know prompting for extension was so unprofessional. but I was in a hurry. i am going to update it.

Comment: thank you @BLUEPIXY for the help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you provide a fix for this program.

Comment: It needs more than one fix. Yes, I could provide a fixed variant of your program, but I won't. I wouldn't learn very much by doing so, and you'd be deprived of the learning opportunity. Plus you'd have to simplify what I provide because it would probably do things you haven't thought of or learned about yet.

Comment: it's ok @JonathanLeffler.and thanks too.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem lies in the `strcat(".",filext)` part of
 `fp = fopen(strcat(filename,strcat(".",filext)),"w");`

Try

```
strcat(filename, ".");
strcat(filename, filext);
fp = fopen(filename, "w");
```

And it might be better if the function definition header was made 
`int create(char filename[SIZE])` (where `SIZE` is a value less than the size `filename` will be) instead of `int create(char* filename)` since you are using `strcat()` to modify the string in the user-defined function `create()`. You wouldn't want illegal memory accesses that would cause errors if the string encroaches upon the memory allotted to something else.

A similar problem is there with using `strcat()` to modify the string at `argv[1]` as pointed out by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for which [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) has provided a solution in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot